# Spring hello world example error

Tags: eclipse, spring, libraries

I have this error:

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 2 in XML document from class path resource [Beans.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.tutorialspoint.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:10)

 Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPIData(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanPIData(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPI(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:389)
```

I have add these libraries:

- commons-logging-1.1.3
- spring-aop-4.0.0.M1
- spring-aspects-4.0.0.M1
- spring-beans-4.0.0.M1
- spring-context-4.0.0.M1
- spring-context-support-4.0.0.M1
- spring-core-4.0.0.M1
- antlr-runtime-3.0.1

My code:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class HelloWorld {
    private String message;

    public void setMessage(String message){
        this.message  = message;
    }

    public void getMessage(){
        System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
    }
}


package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");

        obj.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-
 3.0.xsd"
 >
    <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorld">
        <property name="message" value="Hello World!" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Try adding schema location for instance

Comment: The similar error was here , I think this should work

http://stackoverflow.com/a/23987300/1572347

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try not to split these xml into multiple lines:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-
 3.0.xsd"
```

Often newlines and whitespaces inside XML attribute values are treated as literal. Use this instead:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"
```

Comment: thanks all.
where should i begin with spring? y'all have any book or website for beginner?
sorry, my english's not so well.

Comment: I recommend http://www.amazon.com/books/dp/0764574833 because it's written by Rod Johnson and Juergen Hoeller (both creator / lead of Spring framework)

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem.
there should not be any space at the start of the 1st line
i.e.
this is line

```
no space<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, corrected that the first line should Beans.xml should start with (no empty line in the first line)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `spring-expression-3.x.x.RELEASE` jar through java build path

Comment: This didn't worked , still getting Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure that there is no space, empty line or comment in the first line before `?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.

I had a comment in the first line and after moving it down the problem was solved.